# What is the HTML for an epsilon ampersand

Tags: html

I am new to writing code. Is there a html or CSS code for the epsilon ampersand? It is a lower case epsilon with a tick above and bellow.

Thanks.

Comment: What you're looking for are called HTML entities. The code for an epsilon is `&epsilon;` If you Google "HTML entities" and the symbol, there are lots of reference website. [This one](http://www.webstandards.org/learn/reference/charts/entities/symbol_entities/) has many of the Greek symbols.

Comment: An "epsilon" and an "epsilon ampersand" are two different things. Maybe someone voted this comment down because they thought I was looking for a unicode epsilon .Nope. Looking for the epsilon ampersand.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no [epsilon ampersand](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aEpsilon_Ampersand.png) in unicode. There is only one ampersand:

```
&amp; &AMP;
```

There are however many epsilons:

```
&Epsilon; &epsiv; &varepsilon; &epsilon; &epsi; &straightepsilon; &bepsi; &backepsilon;
```

See them on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sts56/). You can find a list of available characters [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
&Epsilon;
```

or

```
&#917;
```

Lower case:

```
&#949;
```

[Source](http://ancienthistory.about.com/od/greeklanguage/a/ASCIIGreek.htm)